# React Native component not rendering correctly when some children are removed

Tags: react-native

I want to allow a user to toggle `Text` components present or not present by setting a boolean state which I called `pinyinMode`.

```
return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
      <Pressable style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>{hanzi}</Text>
        {pinyinMode && <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>{pinyin}</Text>}
      </Pressable>
    </View>
);
```

Referring to the screenshots below, the `View` does not resize around its children when `pinyinMode` is `false`. (I also decreased the `fontSize: 32` to `fontSize: 20` for the `(` and `)` characters.)

`pinyinMode == true`:

[image: pinyinModeTrue]

`pinyinMode == false`:

[image: pinyinModeFalse]

If remove the `{pinyinMode && <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>{pinyin}</Text>}` line, the `View` renders correctly:

```
return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
      <Pressable style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>{hanzi}</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
);
```

[image]

How can I get the `View` to resize correctly around its children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went with was to create 2 separate components, 1 with the `pinyin` `Text` component, and the other without the `pinyin` `Text` components. I return the first component when `pinyinMode` is true, and return the 2nd component when `pinyinMode` is false.